# What if I give name to a thread but call run() explicitly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that when we call `run()`  explicitly no new thread is started and the code written inside `run()` is executed on the main thread. But what if I give a name to a thread and then call `run()` explicitly as shown in my code?

```
public class ThreadImpl1 extends Thread{

    ThreadImpl1(String name){
        super(name);
        //start();
    }

    public void run() {
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
           System.out.println(getName());
   }

   public static void main(String...s) {
      ThreadImpl1 t1=new ThreadImpl1("thread1");
      t1.run();
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
thread1
thread1
thread1
thread1
thread1
main
main
main
main
main
```

Why does the output show its name i.e. thread1? I haven't started the thread yet so it should print "main" all the time.

Comment: Why should it output _main_? You gave the `Thread` object a name of _thread1_.

Comment: I was expecting main 10 times in output because no new thread was created when I called t1.run() but I forgot that the call to getname() in the run() was implicitly converted to t1.getname() where t1 is the object of ThreadImpl1 class. That's what I was not able to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are calling getName() in the run() method. This will return the value of the field "name" that you set.

You should call Thread.currentThread().getName().

Comment: Yes, when I use Thread.currentThread().getName() instead of getName() in the run(), I get "main" all the time in output. Thank you. Now  I get what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The `run` method will be executed in the current thread just as normal method. No new thread will be created. And, try it to get the definitive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `t1.run();` you do not start the thread but you just call the `run()` method of class `ThreadImpl1` like a regular method.

Just like you call `toString()`... on a class